# Django - app to edit the constants in settings.py in admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there any app available to edit the constants in settings.py in admin interface?

Comment: We will be looking for the app to edit in the admin interface. So that we can avoid the pain of edit the code once it is moved to production.

Comment: This is a Bad Idea. `settings.py` is specifically for settings which *shouldn't* be edited in the admin. Most of those settings require a server restart anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[djblets](http://www.chipx86.com/blog/2008/08/05/django-development-with-djblets-dynamic-site-configuration/) allows dynamic site configuration without having to muck with settings.py.

Answer (score 1):

To change app settings there is the application [django-values](https://code.google.com/p/django-values/). It wouldn't make much sense to manipulate `settings.py` at runtime, because you would need to restart django!

Comment: This is now available as [django-dbsettings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbsettings) from PyPI, and on GitHub at [zlorf/django-dbsettings](https://github.com/zlorf/django-dbsettings).