# Changing settings in settings.py via the webpage/template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I have been recently asked to "hack" into django/python and edit a project. I have never programmed in anything as close to these two languages, so I am studying them on the go.

I did my homework and searched through couple of topics

[Can I access constants in settings.py from templates in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433162/)

[Django - app to edit the constants in settings.py in admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157678/)

and then
http://blog.chipx86.com/2008/08/05/django-development-with-djblets-dynamic-site-configuration/

However, since this is not something I programmed, I have been asked to add some features to admin configuration page to be editable from there and enhance some other portions of the website. I also understand that those require restart of django server.

The guy that did this had site_config.py and settings.py . From the live version of the project, only accessible/editable constants were those from site_config.py. I managed to reproduce those this is how a portion of site_config.py looks like.

```
## SITE #
# Populate default site config values here
SITE_DISPLAY_NAME = 'testing123'
SITE_COMPANY_NAME = 'another123'
```

Now the question is how would I add a portion from urls.py to the given site_config.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # We don't yet have a top-level main view, redirect to AIM app
   (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/aim/'}),
```

This is the portion that I would like to incorporate to the site_config.py. What would I have to do?

If you need more information, please let me know, and I am sorry if this is a newbie question, but I really never worked on anything like this before.
Thank you.

Comment: URLs are not part of the settings file. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I realized that :( I have been trying to make an import from the urls.py, but with no luck. I am trying to make the landing page configurable on the website.

Comment: echo @SimeonVisser, what settings exactly are you trying to make configurable via an interface?  Are they settings for installed applications?  Or do you really mean you want to change things like "MEDIA_ROOT" from the actual settings.py?

Comment: I am trying to make the homepage (when I open 127.0.0.1:8000) to open the page given from the admin/config app. The config app has possibility to change the path to css file, logo file, and all the stuff from site_config.py. That is where I would like to include the possibility to change the link for homepage. I hope I was a bit clearer, sorry for the confusion. PS portion of the site_config.py is included in the original post and I will include some here too.
    BANNER_HREF = ' '
    CUSTOM_CSS_URL = ' '
    FAVICON_ICO = ' '
    MENU_EXTRA_LINK = ' '